# Bootstrap Affix changes width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I am applying the Bootstrap affix property on a `thead` element. Though its successfully applied, the width which should be `970px` is lost (On further reading i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309980/bootstrap-affix-changing-list-item-width)). However, though i manually set the width of `thead` to be `970px`, the `tr > th` are still not spread completely.

BEFORE: [image]

After: [image]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Qm22kH3sLz

NOTE: Also notice, the shift in the Board column and Status column

Comment: Could you try to create a fiddle and, can you try in Css : "thead.affix{width:970px;}"

Comment: Included! Please check again